# How to stop the jmeter server from command line

Tags: performance, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

We are implementing CI for performance testing, As a part of this we have to run scripts from 3 different machines,  I am facing an issue while stoping the Jmeter server in slave machines after the execution.

I am executing the shutdown.bat, stoptest.bat but no luck.

Please help me, How to stop the Jmeter server from the command prompt which is currently running.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Configure your `jmeter.properties` file like this `server.exitaftertest=true`. It will stop the JMeter-server after the test execution.